# Why no ICMP error message is generated for a fragmented datagram that is not the first fragment?

Tags: networking, icmp

> No ICMP error message will be generated for a fragmented datagram that is not the first fragment.
>   - Data Communications and Networking by FOROUZAN

Why?

Answer (score 2):

The original RFC which defines ICMP, [RFC 792, INTERNET CONTROL MESSAGE PROTOCOL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792), makes this rule:

> The ICMP messages typically report errors in the processing of
> datagrams.  To avoid the infinite regress of messages about messages
> etc., no ICMP messages are sent about ICMP messages.  Also **ICMP
>
> messages are only sent about errors in handling fragment zero of
>
> fragemented datagrams.  (Fragment zero has the fragment offeset equal
> zero).**

Answer (score 0):

Only the first fragment will have IP header information.
When an ICMP error is sent, the first 8 bytes of the original datagram.
For the first fragment, this 8 bytes (Actual Ip header) will be useful information to the sender, not in the case of other fragments.

Comment: "_Only the first fragment will have IP header information._ that simply isn't true. All fragments of a packet have the same IP header information. The IP header is copied to all fragments, and only the fields dealing with fragments are changed, e.g. Identification, Fragment Offset

Comment: I agree. I was wrong. 
But, it would be sufficient to send ICMP error to the first fragment alone. On seeing this, the sender application can re-send the packet. Does this sound reasonable ?

Answer (score 0):

Only first fragment has TCP header.

when sender received ICMP, there is 2 types of header in ICMP data section. (IP, TCP)

The sender can check the TCP header to recover what is wrong.

but, if not first fragment, There is no data to check what is wrong

so, ICMP only generated for a first fragment. Because sender cannot do anything.

Comment: how does this answer the question whatsoever?

Comment: if icmp has a TCP header (in data section), when sender received, sender know what is fault. but if there is no TCP header, sender cannot do anything. It's unnecessary. english so hard.. :(

Comment: It might be a good idea to edit that in to make your answer more clear